# API gateway is returning extra data error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-rds

Below is my python lambda function

```
import sys
import logging
import pymysql
import json
import boto3
rds_host="rds.amazonaws.com"
name="name"
password="pass"
db_name="DB"
port = 3306
def save_events(event):
result = []
conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, 
connect_timeout=30)
with conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor) as cur:
cur.execute("select exid,exercise_name,image from exercise where bid = event['params']['querystring']['Bid']")
result = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
print ("Data from RDS...")
print (result)
workout = json.dumps(result)
workouts=(workout.replace("\"", "'"))

def lambda_handler(event, context):
save_events(event)
return workouts
```

I created get method in API gateway and integrated with the above lambda function, In method request, I gave query string as "Bid" and in Integration request, I added mapping template as "Bid":"$input.params('bid')", when I test the API giving query parameters as "Bid=1" it is returning the below error

```
{"errorMessage": "Extra data: line 1 column 6 (char 5)", "errorType": "JSONDecodeError", "stackTrace": [["/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", 354, "loads", "return _default_decoder.decode(s)"], ["/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", 342, "decode", "raise JSONDecodeError(\"Extra data\", s, end)"]]}
```

I used lambda proxy integration too and am getting same above error. Please help i got struck here, Thanks  in advance.

Comment: Check your question, it is difficult to understand the procedural error causing JSONDecodeError https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the output of `print (result)`?  A culprit is that your sql is incorrect and doe not properly bind the lambda event data.  Betting your are parsing not-JSON.